# Android free store/retrieve cloud options

Tags: android, cloud

I was wondering if there are any free options to store and retrieve data from the cloud with Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use parse.com for object cloud storage, and it's really simple to use, see http://www.parse.com

Comment: Thanks! That looks really cool. How does it scale when having a lot of traffic and users? Are there fees involved?

Comment: Sorry, I see there billing service. I was wondering if the user has to log in with there service or something?

Comment: It's free until 1 000 000 request per month, you can create free account easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google App Engine. It is free up to a certain limit. After that threshold you have to pay if you want additional storage and/or traffic.

Comment: Does the user have to log in with a Google account?

Comment: Nope. You need to make a google apps account yourself (you as a developer) and setup the cloud service with the servlet and code which will handle the requests sent by the mobile devices. The users themselves do not have to log in with any accounts unless you make use of google's authentication tokens for part of the information exchange.

Comment: Out of your point of view, what do you believe is the better choice to go with: Google App Engine or parse.com?

Comment: I have never used parse.com, but you can get more information about Google App Engine's billing here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/billing
I personally liked the flexibility and detail that Google App Engine would let you go into and I would pick it again over another alternative. It has got great tools for managing your application.
I have looked at parse.com website briefly and it seems that they have APIs which might let you develop faster, but they focus in cloud storage alone, while Google App Engine gives you more freedom in implementing logic along with that storage.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to only store and retrieve data from cloud, you could use Google App engine which is pretty easy to use. It has APIs in Java and python
If you want more control over how you store the data, you should create an account with Amazon Web services and try using S3. Overall, Amazon S3 will also turn out to be cheaper than Google App Engine.